# How to conficure django LOGGING with azure-log-analytics?

Tags: python, django, azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

I have a Django app, I want to log to azure log analytics

I used Application Insights so far and it is worked with my code, but I don't understand this new way of logging. ( I had to change because Azure said that outdated )

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,

    "handlers": {
        'azure_log_analytics': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'azure.loganalytics.handlers.LogAnalyticsHandler',
            'workspace_id': os.environ.get('LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID', None),
            'workspace_key': os.environ.get('LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_KEY', None),
        },
    },

    "loggers": {
        "API": {
            "handlers": ["azure_log_analytics"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False,
        },

    }
}
```

ValueError: Cannot resolve 'azure.loganalytics.handlers.LogAnalyticsHandler': No module named 'azure.loganalytics.handlers'

Answer (score 0):

You probably still need to install the package for it.
Can be done here:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-loganalytics/

One of these should likely work for your environment! ;)

```bash
py -m pip install azure-mgmt-loganalytics
python -m pip install azure-mgmt-loganalytics
python3 -m pip install azure-mgmt-loganalytics
```